# Jsefa inserts double quotes in csv file

Tags: java, csv, escaping, double-quotes, jsefa

I have the object like this:

```
@CsvDataType()
public class MyCsvDto implements Serializable {

    @CsvField(pos = 1)
    private String str1;

    @CsvField(pos = 4)
     private String str4;

    @CsvField(pos = 3)
     private String str3;

    @CsvField(pos = 2)
    private String str2;
}
```

If one of the field contains value:

```
"{"792":{"cust":"\n"},"104":{"firmMnemonic":"FSWB","houseAccountNum":104,"branchCode":"AL","floorBrokerNum":"781","cust":"\n"},"264":{"firmMnemonic":"FMST","houseAccountNum":264,"floorBrokerNum":"334","cust":"\n"}}"
```

result in csv looks like this:

```
"{""792"":{""firmMnemonic"":""AAAA"",""houseAccountNum"":111,""houseSuffix"":null,""branchCode"":""A111"",""branchSeqno"":null,""floorBrokerNum"":""A111"",""secondaryFloorBrokerNum"":null,""billingIndicator"":null,""cust"":""\n"",""cmta"":null,""supplementaryInfo"":null,""allOrNone"":null,""houseAccountInfo"":""111""},""104"":{""firmMnemonic"":""FSWB"",""houseAccountNum"":104,""houseSuffix"":null,""branchCode"":""AL"",""branchSeqno"":null,""floorBrokerNum"":""A111"",""secondaryFloorBrokerNum"":null,""billingIndicator"":null,""cust"":""\n"",""cmta"":null,""supplementaryInfo"":null,""allOrNone"":null,""houseAccountInfo"":""104""},""264"":{""firmMnemonic"":""FMST"",""houseAccountNum"":264,""houseSuffix"":null,""branchCode"":""A111"",""branchSeqno"":null,""floorBrokerNum"":""A111"",""secondaryFloorBrokerNum"":null,""billingIndicator"":null,""cust"":""\n"",""cmta"":null,""supplementaryInfo"":null,""allOrNone"":null,""houseAccountInfo"":""264""}}"
```

How to avoid this behaviour ?

Comment: Well ... But this is a correct behavior. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose actually it is hard to explain.  It should not be valid csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private Serializer getSerializer() {
        CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
        config.setFieldDelimiter(';');
        config.setDefaultQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NEVER); //!!!!
        return CsvIOFactory.createFactory(config, MyCsvDto.class).createSerializer();
    }
```